# Timers, dates and script.

Tags: python

So i'm doing a project and have wanted to add some extra features to make it unique.

How do I make it output a timer sort of thing where it would say "It took you (minutes:seconds) to answer this question" after each question and then a overall timer at the end of the exam (Script). Also, how would I add a date on when the exam was taken. What else could i add to make this more unique and users actually interested in doing this. I have simple input features where it asks for their name, class name and then adds up the total score and outputs into a file, named after the class name using 'with' and 'open' commands.

```
OPERATIONS = [             # this is stating what the operations are.
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]
for _ in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)#This will randomly select num1 & num2 to be from 1-10
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS) #this will make the symbol equal to the operations and randomly select it by using .choice
    print("What is", num1, symbol, num2,"?")
    if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):#this will check if the input is true or false by using ValueError if its false.
        print("Well done",name,"you got it correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect, better luck next time!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep state of when you asked the question by using datetime.now() and checking how long it took with datetime.now() - prior time like below. Getting the date is pretty easy as well, datetime.strftime("DD-MM-YYYY") but what I had wrote below has the added benefit of keeping the day as well.

```
OPERATIONS = [             # this is stating what the operations are.
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]
test_begin = datetime.now()
for _ in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)#This will randomly select num1 & num2 to be from 1-10
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS) #this will make the symbol equal to the operations and randomly select it by using .choice
    start = datetime.now()
    print("What is", num1, symbol, num2,"?")
    if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):#this will check if the input is true or false by using ValueError if its false.
        print("Well done",name,"you got it correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect, better luck next time!")
    time_taken = datetime.now() - start

test_length = datetime.now() - test_begin
print(test_length.strftime("DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

Comment: At first, it wouldn't work and said datetime wasn't defined, so I figured i had to import datetime and change the dateime.now() to datetime. It worked. Exept now it wont minus the datetime from the start or test_begin, it says http://imgur.com/ulGXDMc

Comment: sorry you have to do this from datetime import datetime in python they made the datetime library name the same a module within the library.

Comment: @Draguno I guess that means you're giving up on trying to use my solution? :)

Comment: @idjaw No, I tested both of them quickly as I was tired.

Comment: @Draguno. You can do it! :) Take a break and come back to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make use of `time` from the [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) module.

You want one timer that starts when your entire application runs, and then you want a question timer that you reset after every question.

Here is an example. I leave the refactoring of injecting in to your code up to you.

Make use of a dictionary to store your your results so you can easily look them up later. And then you can just output your dictionary for your results.

```
from time import time

exam_time = {}

exam_timer_start = time()
for i in range(1, 10):
    question_timer_start = time()
    answer = input('question')
    exam_time["question_{}".format(i)] = time() - question_timer_start
    question_timer_end = time() - question_timer_start
    print("That question took you {}s to complete".format(question_timer_end))
exam_time["total_exam"] = question_timer_end

print(exam_time)
```

Comment: This is a little confusing on where to put it into my code. I've put it at the start and of course it wont do anything. Do i have to type in question_timer_start and end when I need it to? Also, my questions aren't separate and are randomly generated in a range of 10 for example num1, symbol, num2. As I put it at the start of my code after the imports and 'def's it prints out 'question' in the F5 mode.

Comment: @Draguno I want you to figure this one out. I gave you the solution. Think of it this way: Instead of putting my solution in your code, put your code in my solution, instead. Take that as a hint. Give it a good try. Let your code break a few times. You'll understand it better.

Comment: @Draguno I made a small adjustment to my code. Just to make sure you are using the latest code. Run my code. It works. You will see how it runs, what it is doing. Understand how it works and you will figure out how to put your code inside of that.